# Microsoft Azure ServiceBus Nuget package update issue with visual studio 2015

Tags: azureservicebus

I am getting below error when i tried to install azure service bus nuget package against visual studio 2015

Attempting to gather dependency information for package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.3.2.1 
with respect to project ServiceBusAzure, targeting .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2
Gathering dependency information took 1.23 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.3.2.1

Retrieving package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 3.2.1 from Microsoft and Dot NET
Install failed. Rolling back

Package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.3.2.1 does not exist in folder C:...

Install-Package : Could not install package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 3.2.1. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets. NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2, but the package 
does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Service Bus Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus targets .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.6.1. You will need to update your project to target .NET Framework 4.6.1 or later.

Comment: Thanks Sean Feldman, it worked for me. I missed to change my solution target version to 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus in .Net Framework application. The library is built over .Net Core and it can only be installed in .Net Core or .Net Standard applications.

> Try WindowsAzure.ServiceBus for .Net Framework targeted applications. If your requirement is to install Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, then you need to install it in a intermediate .Net Standard project and you can refer it in your .Net Framework application.

Comment: The library is multi-targeting. See my answer.